# Get Count from all queries in a list of queries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a bunch of "Check" Queries that all should have a Count of 0 if everything is correct. Now I want to create one query to summarize all the Counts of these queries in one list.

Example:

```
QueriesToCheck (Table with one column)
- MissingValues 
- MissingGroup  
- Ais0         

Note: MissingValues (0 rows), MissingGroup (1 row), Ais0 (0 rows) are existing queries in the DB

Expected Output (Query with two columns): 
QueryName            Count
- MissingValues      0
- MissingGroup       1
- Ais0               0

Note: This is a query using the QueriesToCheck table
```

Can somebody give me a hint how to start?

Comment: As your question is now, we have no clue what you are trying to do. Please explain in more detail. Provide us with sample data and expected outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion:

--First of all a *mockup-table* to simulate your issue with system views

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(YourView VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]')
                      ,('sys.objects');
```

--Now we use dynamic SQL generation

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
(                     
    SELECT 'SELECT SUM(CountOfRows) FROM (' 
    + STUFF(
        (                     
            SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ' + t.YourView
            FROM @tbl t         
            FOR XML PATH('')         
        ),1,10,'')
    + ') t(CountOfRows)'
);
```

--And execute this command

```
EXEC(@cmd);
```

The result is a single value summing up all row counts

### The idea in short:

We create a statement like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CountOfRows) 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) 
      FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT COUNT(1) 
      FROM sys.objects) t(CountOfRows)
```

This statement will consist if all queries names you have in your table. The final result is the SUM of all row counts.

### You've edited your question...

This might come closer to your needs, the idea is the same:

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
STUFF(
        (                     
            SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT ''' + t.YourView + ''' AS ViewName,COUNT(1) AS CountOfRows FROM ' + t.YourView
            FROM @tbl t         
            FOR XML PATH('')         
        ),1,10,'');
EXEC(@cmd);
```

The result

```
ViewName                        CountOfRows
[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]  171
sys.objects                     161
```

### UPDATE: Deal with the result as a table

You can use any existing table or a table variable with the syntax `INSERT INTO Target(<ColList>) EXEC(<statement>)`:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(YourView VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]')
                      ,('sys.objects');

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
STUFF(
        (                     
            SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT ''' + t.YourView + ''' AS ViewName,COUNT(1) AS CountOfRows FROM ' + t.YourView
            FROM @tbl t         
            FOR XML PATH('')         
        ),1,10,'');

--Here I use a declared table variable
DECLARE @targetTable TABLE(ViewName VARCHAR(100),CountOfRows INT);

INSERT INTO @targetTable(ViewName,CountOfRows)
EXEC(@cmd);

--we read the result from this table
SELECT * FROM @targetTable;
```

Comment: Mmh, but how do I include your code into a view in SSMS.

Comment: @Krahmi That is impossible in *ad-hoc* queries. You can use a SP.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question. Could you tell me how I insert the result into a table?  That would make my life a lot easier. ^_^

Comment: @Krahmi See my UPDATE section

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows

```
    declare @mytab as table(query nvarchar(max),mytable nvarchar(200),query_count int)
declare @myquery as nvarchar(max)
declare @mycount as int

--Put here the queries you want to check, replace/add Table1,Table2,Table3 by your own tables

insert into @mytab (query,mytable) values
('select @mycount=count(1) from TABLE1','TABLE1'),
('select @mycount=count(1) from TABLE2','TABLE2'),
('select @mycount=count(1) from TABLE3','TABLE3')


declare cursor_count  cursor for select query from @mytab

open cursor_count
fetch cursor_count into @myquery

while @@fetch_status=0
begin
execute sp_executesql 
    @myquery, 
    N'@mycount varchar(max) OUTPUT', 
    @mycount = @mycount output;
update @mytab set query_count=@mycount where query=@myquery;


fetch cursor_count into @myquery
end

close cursor_count

deallocate cursor_count

select mytable,query_count[count] from @mytab
```

Comment: I added some more Information to my question. It was not detailed enough.